# Retrieve JSON from Ajax application and iterate JSON values in another function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, ajax

Just starting out with Ajax but I am having a bit of an issue understanding if this is even possible. I have a db.json file that I am retrieving with Ajax.

```
{
  "transactions": [
{
  "date": "4/3/2021",
  "description": "Electric bill",
  "type": "Debit", "amount": 250.00
},
{
  "date": "1/15/2022",
  "description": "Venmo",
  "type": "Debit",
  "amount": 80.00
}
  ]
}
```

The Ajax function on window.onload

```
window.onload = function () {
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        return jsonObj;
  }
};
ajax.open("GET", "../titan-bank/db.json", true);
ajax.send();
```

Immediately after, the JSON file should be sent over to the this class that will then should iterate through the JSON file and output the information.

```
var transactions = new Transactions;
transactions.getTransactions();

var transactionDisplay = $("transactionDisplay");

class Transactions {
constructor (date, description, type, amount) {
    this.date = date;
    this.description = description;
    this.type = type;
    this.amount = amount;
}
getTransactions () {
    for (let id of values) {
        //adds index for each transaction
        var index = values.indexOf(id) + 1;
        //prints out array of transactions
        transactionDisplay.innerHTML += ("<br>Transaction #" + index + "&emsp;Date: " + id.date +   "&emsp;Description: "
            + id.description + "<br>&emsp;Type: " + id.type + "&emsp;Amount: $"
            + id.amount.toFixed(2) + "<br>");
    }
}
```

Initially I was using "values" from locally available array, but now need to get this information from the JSON file. Any hints as to what I can do here?

Comment: *"Just starting out with Ajax"*: first advice: use `fetch` instead of the old-fashioned `XMLHttpRequest`.

Answer (score 1):

Some remarks:

- If you start with Ajax now, then don't use the `XMLHttpRequest` API, but the `fetch` API. And as you seem to use jQuery, you could even use the [`$.getJSON` function](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getJSON/).
- The class `Transactions` has a constructor that takes the properties of *one* transaction, while the `getTransactions` method is designed to deal with multiple transactions. So your class is mixing up the concept of one transaction and a set of multiple transactions. I would suggest dedicating the class to one transaction only, including a method that returns the HTML rendering of **one** transaction.
- The `values` variable is not defined. With the change proposed in the previous point, you'd have all you need in the instance properties.
- It seems you use jQuery. If "transactionDisplay" is the `id` of an HTML element then the selector should have a hash symbol: `$("#transactionDisplay")`
- As you use jQuery, why not use the `ready` event handler which you can bind by just doing `$(function () {  .... }`.

Here is how I would code it:

```
$(async function () {
    const response = await fetch("../titan-bank/db.json");
    const obj = await response.json();
    const transactions = obj.transactions.map(({date, description, type, amount}, i) => 
        new Transaction(i + 1, date, description, type, amount)
    );
    $("#transactionDisplay").html(transactions.map(transaction => transaction.html()).join("<br><br>"));
});

class Transaction { // One instance is one transaction
    constructor (id, date, description, type, amount) {
        this.id = id; // let's define it here!
        this.date = date;
        this.description = description;
        this.type = type;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
    html() {
        return "Transaction #" + this.id
            + "&emsp;Date: " + this.date 
            + "&emsp;Description: " + this.description
            + "<br>&emsp;Type: " + this.type 
            + "&emsp;Amount: $" + this.amount.toFixed(2);
    }
}
```